# What are the standard Windows preprocessor definitions needed to specify Windows/MFC API version?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I am struggling to figure out a strange AFX-related bug in a C++/MFC module, my working theory is that there is some discrepancy between the way different modules are being built in relation to Windows libraries.

We have various preprocessor settings in project files and header files and I would like to find a standard list of such definitions, so I easily search for all references and check for inconsistencies. For instance I've just spotted that in a single project we have `/D "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501"` *and*  `/D "WINVER=0x0601`

We commonly use variations on:

- WIN32
- _WINDOWS
- _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
- _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600
- WINVER=0x0601
- VC_EXTRALEAN
- _AFXEXT

Are there a list of all those that are commonly used? Are there names for standard values instead of using e.g. `0x0601` Do some of these infer/control others so we can simplify to fewer options in our project files (why do we have WINVER & _WIN32_WINNT)?

I'm concerned I'll try to tidy this all up but miss one definition somewhere I didn't know about!

Comment: *"a strange AFX-related bug"* - A bit more detail on that would likely help you safe time on chasing what eventually turns out to not be a solution.

Comment: Name/Values pairs for `_WIN32_WINNT` and common (IE, etc.) versions are defined here: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared\sdkddkver.h (10.0.22000.0 being the Windows SDK version) this is all what should be used for Windows. AFX, VC are specific to tools (like %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\afxver_.h and afxv_w32.h). You can just run some greps for these, ATL & MFC are open source

Comment: @IInspectable I asked about that before, got nowhere :)

Comment: @SimonMourier but nowhere seems to explain why (it seems) the same thing has to be set in two different variables?

Comment: There's a *lot* of history here (like ~30+ years). But for compiling with today's windows SDK, it's pretty clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers and for upgrades https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt

Comment: When it comes to MFC, I'm not sure that you specify the version to use as a macro; it just depends on what version (headers, library) you actually use in your project. The `_MFC_VER` macro will give you the one in use (as a hex integer literal).